# Preselecting a ListView (WPF) row based on the value of one of its fields

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm new to WFP. I have a WPF ListView bound to a list of tasks. Each item on the list has several fields, one of which is the string field "Status". What I'm trying to achieve is that when this ListView is first loaded and the user sees it, the selected row will be the one where the value of Status if "Fatal". I can assume for this feature that no more than a single row with that status can exist.
Here's my code:

```
 <ListView Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyleFC}" ItemsSource="{Binding CompletedCache.SelectedItem.FilteredTask}" x:Name="_taskListView">
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyleFC}">
                                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource EmptyContextMenu}"/>
                            </Style>                   
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <Helpers:MinWidthColumnListView MinWidth="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" Width="200" x:Name="NameHeader">
                                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Name"/>
                                </Helpers:MinWidthColumnListView>
                                <Helpers:MinWidthColumnListView MinWidth="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TaskStatus}" Width="100" x:Name="TaskStatusHeader" >
                                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Status"/>
                                </Helpers:MinWidthColumnListView>
                                <Helpers:MinWidthColumnListView MinWidth="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RunningComputer}" Width="100" >
                                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Machine"/>
                                </Helpers:MinWidthColumnListView>
                                <Helpers:MinWidthColumnListView MinWidth="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Message}" Width="300" >
                                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Message"/>
                                </Helpers:MinWidthColumnListView>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
```

I've done some reading and saw that you're supposed to add a data trigger inside the style of the ListView.ItemContainerStyle and there present the conditions, but the examples were very unclear and I'm unable to apply them. Can anyone help with a short explanation and a concrete example?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your code? You can use a converter. The input would be the status and the output selected row index.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange: Done. Grant: Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyleFC}">
                                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource EmptyContextMenu}"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=TaskStatus}" Value="Fatal">
                                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>                   
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```